# Is there alternative to IEtester?

Tags: software-recommendation, internet

i used to use ietester in windows for testing site. but i found that it has no downloads for linux. is there any alternative for ietester in ubuntu.

Comment: You might want to give [IE NetRenderer](http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/) a try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install PlayOnLinux, and then use it to install IE7 and/or IE6.

1. First: In software centre install playonlinux
2. Open PlayOnLinux [image]
3. Click install and choose internet [image]
4. Choose the IE version you want and click apply [image]

Comment: That's a nice solution, and is handy for a few other tools.

Answer (score 5):

Not really. And for fairly good reason.

IETester runs multiple versions of Internet Explorer. You can *just about* run IE in Wine but it's neither a pleasant experience (not that it is in Windows) or is it guaranteed to be representative of what Windows users are actually seeing.

Your best bet is to either outsource this sort of testing to something like BrowserShots et al either for free or a small amount of money each month (you often get what you pay for), or install something like VirtualBox and run a small virtual XP install when you want to test IE and Window's versions of other browsers.

I tend to do both:

- I'll do initial development in native Firefox
- Then I'll test in a VirtualBoxxed XP install, go back and make whatever fixes I need.
- Then I ship the whole thing off to BrowserShots so I can see how it looks on other platforms at the same time.

Comment: i use virtualbox and i tried in wine too but i was expecting if there is for ubuntu itself. thanks for your answer.

Comment: here is what i found but it has only ie 6. http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/page/Main_Page

Comment: i also found that we can test with http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/index.php

Comment: Yeah there are dozens of services like that. Some free. Some that offer a lot more features that you have to pay a little for.

Comment: IE7 runs in wine.

Answer (score 1):

Also have a look at [linie](http://code.google.com/p/linie/), which looks promising and actively developed, although I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

[modern.ie](http://modern.ie/en-gb/virtualization-tools#downloads): Free Windows virtual machines from Microsoft with a variety of IE versions available.

Answer (score 0):

an online tool provided by microsoft: [browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com) which is 19$/Month but you can try the trial for a while.

Comment: Best for who, Microsoft's accounting department? It would be helpful to mention that Browserstack is a closed-source, proprietary system with [prices starting at $19/Month](https://www.browserstack.com/pricing). Interesting service, but definitely not what I would call the 'best'.

Comment: How is a paid closed source the best?  In a community where we prize freedom both in terms of liberty and price you need to justify that statement.

Comment: Well apologies, my bad using "best". but still i think free trial worth a try

Answer (score -1):

You can try LambdaTest https://www.lambdatest.com/ the pricing starts at $19, even we use the same.